# What kind of material could be used as a diffraction grating for Xrays?

Tags: solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, crystals, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I'm trying to design a home-built X-ray fluorescence spectrometer with the following layout:

[image]

Building the X-ray tube is relatively simple, however I'm uncertain what material could be used as the 'crystal' in this setup?

According to this [article](https://doi.org/10.1515/psr-2016-0061), a lithium fluoride crystal could do the trick, but I'm wondering if people here have thoughts on what  the optimal setup is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whatever single crystal you have. The cheapest high quality single crystals are Si wafers.

Another more DIY-type option might be taking an old GPU or CPU die and grinding it off somewhat until you reach the bulk Si part.